# .NET Core NuGet restore fails with private NuGet feed (VSTS CI Build)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-pipelines

This issue is regarding the continuous integration feature in visual studio team services, specifically in automated builds.

I've set up a build definition to build my .net core mvc application.

It is using .NET core v1 and compiling against .net framework 4.5.2.

I've followed the instructions here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core

I have a private NuGet feed set up in VSTS
Here is the command that adds the package feed source:

```
Sources Add -Name "CiiDLFeed" -UserName "<username>" -Password "<password>" -ConfigFile $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Nuget.config -Source https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/DLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
```

The error I'm receiving:

> error: Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/DLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
>   error:   Password decryption is not supported on .NET Core for this
>   platform. The following feed uses an encrypted password: 'CiiDLFeed'.
>   You can use a clear text password as a workaround.

In response to this, I added "-StorePasswordInClearText" parameter to the NuGet source add command:

```
Sources Add -Name "CiiDLFeed" -UserName "<username>" -Password "<password>" -ConfigFile $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Nuget.config -Source https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/DLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json -StorePasswordInClearText
```

Now, I get a 401 error:

> error: Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/DLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
>   error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401
>   (Unauthorized).

I'm using the same exact credentials that work correctly in a separate build definition, accessing the same nuget feed (a .NET web forms app), so it should not be giving me a 401.

I've also tried simply referencing the library dll's instead of NuGet packages in a private feed, but that appears to be not possible with .NET Core:

> .NET core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies
>   in this release. To reference other assemblies, they need to be
>   included in a NuGet package and reference that package.

Comment: try using v2 for the feed address. I found v3 is not always reliable

Comment: @trailmax I still get 401 error with `v2`. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Are you using your actual password or Personal Access Token as a password?

Comment: @trailmax My actual username and password. The output displays it like that for some reason.

Comment: Try using Personal Access Token (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) but make sure you give according permissions for package management. If that works - there is even better way.

Comment: You can see example of the nuget.config file here http://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/nuget-configuration-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround solution we used is to setup a local NuGet source that is a directory in the project. Then add your .nupkg files to it, and reference them in your project.

This allows the VSTS CI build to access your NuGet package without setting up a remote NuGet source.

eg:

```
project_directory/
    ... project files ...
    my_nuget_repo/
        mypackage.nupkg
```

Add the local source:

```
nuget sources add -Name "my_nuget_repo" -Source "<path_to_project>/my_nuget_repo"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to your own Nuget.Config file instead (Can use PAT as password):

1. Add Nuget.Config file (include the corresponding packageSource) to source control
2. Edit your build definition
3. Remove/disable Command line step that used to add package source
4. Select .Net Core (Preview) Restore step.

arguments like:

```
--configfile $(build.sourcesdirectory)/ConsoleAppCore/Nuget.Config
```

Note: You can create or edit a NuGet.config at the solution root, next to the project.json file and check into source control, with this way, you don't need to specify configfile argument for .Net Core restore step.

Comment: Would you include the syntax for specifying NuGet source inside of NuGet.config?

Comment: @JamesWierzba The syntax is like you said that nuget sources add ..., do it in you local machine and corresponding Nuget.config (%APPDATA%\NuGet by default) to source control.

Comment: @JamesWierzba Using PAT is the better way and it works fine for me. Try to use PAT as the password and check the result.

Comment: We strongly recommend not checking your PAT into source control; anyone with access to your PAT can interact with Azure DevOps Services as you. -- says Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav